# Extending class with lots of methods and hiding most of them

Tags: java

I am creating a custom JDialog class and I am wondering how can I hide all the methods I don't want someone to change?

As a 'result' I just want the methods to be visible that really matter.

E.g.

```
public class TestDialog extends JDialog {
    public void setProgress(int p) {}
}
```

and when someone wants to use this dialog all he sees is:

```
testDialog.setProgress // suggested from eclipse
```

UPDATE: I want to hide all the methods from JDialog if that wasn't clear

Comment: Is something preventing your from making those other methods private or protected?

Comment: No. But there are so many that I thought maybe there is an easier way to do this

Comment: If you don't want your methods to be visible and want to protect them from getting overidden make them private and final.

Comment: Sorry I think I wasn't clear enough with this. I want to hide all the methods of JDialog

Comment: You cannot do that. You need set the desired visibility on the superclass. But that's not possible if you haven't got the sources.<br>
Anyways, why would you do that? As a solution you could wrap the JDialog.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an own class, that is not extending a JDialog, but containing one.

Example:

```
public class MyDialog{

    private JDialog dia = null;

    public MyDialog() {
        //init dialog
    }

    //your methods, ...

    public void setXYZ(int a) {
        dia.setXYZ(a);
    }

}
```

This way you only need to implement methods, you want to be visible.

**EDIT**

For better understanding have a look at different design patterns (for example: [deligation pattern](http://best-practice-software-engineering.ifs.tuwien.ac.at/patterns/delegation.html) and [adapter pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern))

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered wrapping the class instead of extending it? This is generaly preferred, particularly if you do not actually want to keep most of the existing methods.

See for example: [Avoid extending classes](http://www.billharlan.com/papers/Avoid_extending_classes.html), or the [Delegation pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern) on Wikipedia.